# Группированный input jquery

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста такой скрипт или плагин, который реализует input с возможностью добавлять или удалять слова, фразы.
Прошу прощения, я даже не знаю как назвать его.

[image: Группированный input]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Визуально похоже на плагин [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), а конкретно [Multiple select boxes](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Есть возможность вводить свои значения если нет в списке нужных, называются [теги](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    tags: true
});
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но больше понравился скрипт самописный, который предложил Yuri. Он намного меньше по объему. Но Ваш ответ тоже полезен. Спасибо!

Comment: Все же плагин лучше, хотя большой объем, это жаль.

Comment: не подскажите как принимать данные теперь через POST, а то не могу принять их, приходит только один параметр.

Comment: input name сделайте в виде массива, если было name="country" сделайте name="country[]"

Comment: Спасибо, совсем забыл про []

Answer (score 3):

Это называется *Multiple input*. Могу предложить три варианта:

1. [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple):

   ```js
   $(function() {
     var availableTags = [
       "ActionScript",
       "AppleScript",
       "Asp",
       "BASIC",
       "C",
       "C++",
       "Clojure",
       "COBOL",
       "ColdFusion",
       "Erlang",
       "Fortran",
       "Groovy",
       "Haskell",
       "Java",
       "JavaScript",
       "Lisp",
       "Perl",
       "PHP",
       "Python",
       "Ruby",
       "Scala",
       "Scheme"
     ];

     function split(val) {
       return val.split(/,\s*/);
     }

     function extractLast(term) {
       return split(term).pop();
     }

     $("#tags")
       // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
       .on("keydown", function(event) {
         if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
           $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
           event.preventDefault();
         }
       })
       .autocomplete({
         minLength: 0,
         source: function(request, response) {
           // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
           response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
             availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
         },
         focus: function() {
           // prevent value inserted on focus
           return false;
         },
         select: function(event, ui) {
           var terms = split(this.value);
           // remove the current input
           terms.pop();
           // add the selected item
           terms.push(ui.item.value);
           // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
           terms.push("");
           this.value = terms.join(", ");
           return false;
         }
       });
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

   <div class="ui-widget">
     <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
     <input id="tags" size="50">
   </div>
   ```
2. Мой скрипт:

   ```js
   // Скрипт
   $(function() {
     $('[role="select"]').each(function() {
       var e = this;
       // Обромляем содержимое в блок и добавляем ещё одно поле для добавления тегов
       $(e).html('<div role="field"></div><div role="list">' + $(e).html() + '</div>');
       var field = $(this).find('[role="field"]'), // Получаем блок с где будут сохраняться теги
         list = $(this).find('[role="list"]'); // Получаем блок с option
       $(e).val(''); // Создаём для элемента [role="select"] значение value
       // Проверяем, есть ли выбранные option
       if (list.find('option[selected]').length > 0) {
         // Если да, то создаём для каждого option функцию
         list.find('option[selected]').each(function() {
           var val = $(this).attr('value') || $(this).text(); // Получаем значение option из атрибута value или, если его нет, из содержимого
           // Проверяем, пустое ли поле с тегами
           if ($(e).val() == '') {
             $(e).val(val); // Если пустое, то просто добавляем значение val
           } else {
             $(e).val($(e).val() + ',' + val); // Если не пустое, то к содержимому добавляем запятую и значение option. Делаем что-то типа массива
           };
           var tag = $('<span role="tag">' + $(this).text() + ' <span role="remove">x</span></span>'); // Создаём тег
           tag.prop('index', $(this).index()).val(val); // Записываем в него индекс соответствующего option и 
           field.append(tag); // Добавляем тег в конец поля
           $(this).hide(); // Скрываем элемент option
         });
       };
       // Создаём функцию нажатия на option
       $(e).on('click', 'option', function() {
         var val = $(this).attr('value') || $(this).text(), // Получаем значение value элемента option и если его нет, то его содержимое
           valArr = $(e).val().split(','); // Создаём из значения value элемента [role="select"] массив, что бы проверить на наличие элемента
         // Проверяем, добавлено ли уже это значение в value элемента [role="select"], что бы пользователь не мог добавить копию значения
         if(valArr.indexOf(val) == -1){
           // Если значения в value элемента [role="select"] нет, то проверяем value на содержимое. Пустое ли оно
           if ($(e).val() == '') {
             // Если да, то просто добавляем val в value
             $(e).val(val);
           } else {
             // Если value не пустое, то к содержимому добавляем запятую и значение val. Создаём что-то вроде строчного массива
             $(e).val($(e).val() + ',' + val);
           };
           var tag = $('<span role="tag">' + $(this).text() + ' <span role="remove">x</span></span>'); // Создаём тег
           tag.prop('index', $(this).index()).val(val); // Записываем в тег индекс элемента option, на который нажали и его val
           field.append(tag); // Добавляем тег в конец поля
           $(this).hide(); // Прячем option
           list.hide(); // Скрываем список с option, для эффекта :)
         };
       // Создаём функцию нажатия на поле с тегами
       }).on('click', '[role="field"]', function() {
         list.toggle(); // Открываем или закрываем список с option при нажатии на поле с тегами
       // Создаём функцию удаления тега из списка при нажатии на [role="remove"]
       }).on('click', '[role="remove"]', function() {
         var optInx = $(this).parent('[role="tag"]').prop('index'), // Получаем из тега индекс соответствующего option
             val = $(this).parent('[role="tag"]').val(); // Получаем из тега value соответствующего option
         $(this).parent('[role="tag"]').remove(); // Удаляем тег
         list.find('option').eq(optInx).show(); // Ищем нужный option по индексу и показываем его
         var valArr = $(e).val().split(','); // Создаём из значений value элемента [role="select"] массив для удаления значения
         valArr.splice(valArr.indexOf(val),1); // С помощью функции indexOf ищем положение нужно value в массиве и удаляем его
         $(e).val(valArr.join(',')); // Создаём из массива строку и переписываем значение value в [role="select"]
       });
     });
     // Создаём функцию нажатия на любой элемент сайта
     $(document).click(function(e) {
       // Проверяем, нажатие было на элемент [role="field"] или нет
       if($(e.target).closest('[role="field"]').length == 0){
         // Если нет, то скрываем список option
         $('[role="list"]').hide();
       };
     });
   });

   // Проверка значение
   $(function() {
     $('button').click(function() {
       console.log($('[role="select"]').val());
     });
   });
   ```

   ```css
   [role="select"] {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
   }
   [role="select"] > [role="field"] {
     display: block;
     -webkit-appearance: menulist;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     align-items: center;
     white-space: pre;
     width: 300px;
     min-height: 27px;
     padding: 1px;
     -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     cursor: default;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-image: initial;
     border-radius: 0px;
     border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
     font-size: 13px;
     font-family: arial;
   }
   [role="select"] > [role="field"] > [role="tag"] {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: #dddddd;
     padding: 3px;
     margin: 1px;
     border-radius: 3px;
   }
   [role="select"] > [role="field"] > [role="tag"] > [role="remove"] {
       display: inline-flex;
       margin-left: 3px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       background-color: #cfcfcf;
       width: 15px;
       height: 15px;
       cursor: pointer;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
   }
   [role="select"] > [role="list"] {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin: -1px 0 0 0;
     border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
     background-color: white;
     font-size: 13px;
     font-family: arial;
   }
   [role="select"] > [role="list"] > option {
     display: block;
     color: black;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   [role="select"] > [role="list"] > option:hover {
     background-color: #1b8bfa;
     color: white;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div role="select" name="myselect">
     <option value="Значение 1" selected>Пункт 1</option>
     <option value="Значение 2">Пункт 2</option>
     <option value="Значение 3">Пункт 3</option>
   </div>
   <button>Показать значение select</button>
   ```
3. Другие библиотеки и отдельные скрипты: [Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), [Отдельный скрипт](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/98818/A-multiple-input-control-using-JQuery), [MetroUICSS](https://metroui.org.ua/select2.html)

Comment: Взял Ваш самописный, так как он меньше по объему, спасибо!

Comment: @Владимир, это радует :) Но я не уверен, что там нету костылей, так как писал давненько :-D

Comment: кстати, сейчас заметил, что мне трудно будет разобраться и времени особо нет, что бы выбранные данные приходили в посте, поэтому передумал) Сори, вынужден выбрать другой ответ с плагином правильный.